# Antlr AST tree construction

Tags: java, tree, antlr, grammar, antlr3

I'm trying to create an AST using ANTLR tree grammar.

Given a syntax like following:

```
rule    : head ':-' litlist (';' ':-' litlist)* DOT_END
```

I want to create a tree like following

```
 ^(RULES ^(head litlist)+)
```

That is, I want `(head litlist)` to be repeated as many as the number of `litlist` in the syntax. I tried something like above, but I'm getting an error like this:

> Syntax error:required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input EXPR 
>   where EXPR is another term in the grammar.

Basically I want something like following:

```
a : type ID (',' ID)* ';' -> ^(type ID)+;
```

which is described in [Tree constructon](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Tree+construction).

But my syntax has multiple tokens inside repeated clause, which seems to be a problem.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried another level of indirection? Such as:

```
rule    : clauses DOT_END ->  ^(RULES clauses)
clauses : head ':-' litlist (';' ':-' litlist)* -> ^(head litlist)+
```

Maybe the syntax is not proper yet.